# HostPath volume on AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, eksctl

Deployed Kubernetes deployment on AWS EKS.

Kubernetes Pod has some jars, which are required to patch (java jar with some changes) in development process. These jars are kept in EKS worker node’s `/tmp` folder as hostPath volume. But unfortunately pod is unable to access those jars

Same deployment and same hostPath volumes are working in local kubernetes cluster.

What I am missing here ?

```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /root/app
  name: patch-jar

volumes:
- hostPath:
     path: /tmp
     type: DirectoryOrCreate
  name: patch-jar
```

Comment: Please add your yaml file as a reference.

Comment: Added code snippet for reference

Answer (score 0):

Switched syntax for this one, works perfectly for me:

```yaml
volumeMounts:
  - name: patch-jar
    mountPath: /root/app

volumes:
 - name: 
   hostPath:
   path: /tmp
   type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Also, use `kubectl get events -n your-namespace` for debugging.